# How to return js custom alert from controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript

currently my code in controller is like this :

- I want to return sweet alert js custom message . So I have given link for sweet alert in return content and calling swal but its not working for me :

  ```
  string hh = Url.Content("~/Styles/sweetalert.css");
  return Content("<link href='" + hh + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>" + "<script src='/Scripts/sweetalert-dev.js'></script>" + "<script src='/Scripts/sweetalert.min.js'></script>)" + "<Script>swal('hiiii');</script>");
  ```

**Edit:**
I am sending direct href from client side and downloading csv and pdf and if an error occur then i want to show custom alert from controller . So i can't use ajax here . Please suggest me here how to use partial view or any other option .

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax to custom alert instead,
Or render PartialView include your custom script.